# Custom ID with ObjectBox

Tags: flutter, objectbox

I'm using ObjectBox with Flutter and I'm having some trouble with the mandatory `int id` required by ObjectBox on each `Entity`.

In my app I'm using custom ids using the [uuid package](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) and I'm mapping those `Entity` classes to my own `Domain` classes to make abstraction of the ObjectBox implementation.

Those `Entity` classes have the mandatory `int id` required by ObjectBox that I defined as `int obid` annotated with `@Id()` and my own `Domain` id defined as `String id` with the `@Unique()` annotation.

It just gives me a little bit more work when I need to get an `Entity` by id, but that's fine. The problem is when I need to add an `Entity` having a relation with another one, since my `Domain` classes don't have the `obid` when I convert from a `Domain` to an `Entity` class, the `obid` is omitted and defaults to 0, then ObjectBox tries to persist/create a new `Entity` and fail because of the `@Unique()` annotation of the `id`. I don't even want to create a new `Entity` for the relation. What I want is create an `Entity` and just put a reference to an already persisted `Entity` as the the relation.

I think the way to do it is by setting `relation.target` or the `relation.targetId` but in my case, this won't work because it doesn't rely on my `id`.

How can I make my own `id` work as a real id and not just a `Unique` constraint ?

Here are some examples of those `Entity` and `Domain` classes :

DocumentTemplateEntity :

```
@Entity()
class DocumentTemplateEntity {
  @Id()
  int obid = 0;

  @Unique()
  String id;
  String title;
  double leftMargin;
  double topMargin;
  double rightMargin;
  double bottomMargin;
  DateTime? insertedAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  final family = ToOne<DocumentFamilyEntity>();

  DocumentTemplateEntity({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.leftMargin,
    required this.topMargin,
    required this.rightMargin,
    required this.bottomMargin,
    this.insertedAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  DocumentTemplate toDomain() => DocumentTemplate(
        id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(id),
        title: DocumentTemplateTitle(title),
        leftMargin: leftMargin,
        topMargin: topMargin,
        rightMargin: rightMargin,
        bottomMargin: bottomMargin,
        insertedAt: insertedAt,
        updatedAt: updatedAt,
        family: family.target!.toDomain(),
      );

  factory DocumentTemplateEntity.fromDomain(DocumentTemplate template) =>
      DocumentTemplateEntity(
        id: template.id.getOrCrash(),
        title: template.title.getOrCrash(),
        leftMargin: template.leftMargin,
        topMargin: template.topMargin,
        rightMargin: template.rightMargin,
        bottomMargin: template.bottomMargin,
        insertedAt: template.insertedAt,
        updatedAt: template.updatedAt,
      )..family.target = DocumentFamilyEntity.fromDomain(template.family);
}
```

DocumentFamilyEntity :

```
@Entity()
class DocumentFamilyEntity {
  @Id()
  int obid = 0;

  @Unique()
  String id;
  String title;
  int sortOrder;
  DateTime? insertedAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;

  DocumentFamilyEntity({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.sortOrder,
    this.insertedAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  DocumentFamily toDomain() => DocumentFamily(
        id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(id),
        title: title,
        sortOrder: sortOrder,
        insertedAt: insertedAt,
        updatedAt: updatedAt,
      );

  factory DocumentFamilyEntity.fromDomain(DocumentFamily family) =>
      DocumentFamilyEntity(
        id: family.id.getOrCrash(),
        title: family.title,
        sortOrder: family.sortOrder,
        insertedAt: family.insertedAt,
        updatedAt: family.updatedAt,
      );
}
```

DocumentTemplate (Domain) :

```
@freezed
class DocumentTemplate with _$DocumentTemplate {
  factory DocumentTemplate({
    required UniqueId id,
    required DocumentTemplateTitle title,
    required double leftMargin,
    required double topMargin,
    required double rightMargin,
    required double bottomMargin,
    required DocumentFamily family,
    DateTime? insertedAt,
    DateTime? updatedAt,
  }) = _DocumentTemplate;

  factory DocumentTemplate.initial() => DocumentTemplate(
        id: UniqueId(),
        title: DocumentTemplateTitle(''),
        leftMargin: 1.0,
        topMargin: 1.0,
        rightMargin: 1.0,
        bottomMargin: 1.0,
        family: DocumentFamily.initial(),
      );
}
```

DocumentFamily (Domain) :

```
@freezed
class DocumentFamily with _$DocumentFamily {
  factory DocumentFamily({
    required UniqueId id,
    required int sortOrder,
    required String title,
    DateTime? insertedAt,
    DateTime? updatedAt,
  }) = _DocumentFamily;

  factory DocumentFamily.initial() => DocumentFamily(
        id: UniqueId(),
        sortOrder: 0,
        title: '',
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly assumed you can set `relation.target` (or `relation.targetId`) - it can point to an existing object, in which case ObjectBox won't try to create it. An adaptation of the following code should work for you:

```dart
final docTemplate = DocumentTemplateEntity(...)
final familyQuery = store.box<DocumentFamilyEntity>().query(DocumentFamilyEntity_.id.equals('unique ID of an existing family entity').build();

// and one of the following
docTemplate.family.target = familyQuery.findFirst(); 
// or
docTemplate.family.targetId = (familyQuery..limit = 1).findIds().firstOrNull;
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like the only solution for now but I found out that with ObjectBox Java, you had the option of adding a parameter to the @Unique() annotation (something like @Unique(onConflict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE) ) that would replace the Entity in the case it already existed. As referenced here : https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/509#issuecomment-851838735

I guess it would solve my problem and make the @Unique() annotation behave more like a real ID. Will this feature come to ObjectBox Dart too ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone working on this at the moment. If that's something you'd like to use, you can create a feature request (issue) on github for objectbox-dart. Even better, you can contribute the change :)

Comment: Hello! I saw you're a objectbox's collaborator, what about a `ConflictStrategy.UPDATE` @vaind ? https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/378